# auto scroll with overflow text? (with no visible scoll bar)

Tags: html, css

Ok so I have a little box popup with some text on it that reads from a text file so the text that appears in the box isn't always the same. Im utilizing the overflow feature in css but is there anyway to get an auto scroll of the overflown text, and without the scroll bar?

```
body{
background-color: black;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-size: 20;
}  

#Track{
color: white;
position: fixed;
top: 20px;
left: -500px;
animation-name: track;
animation-duration: 30s;
z-index: 1;
width: 200px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: scroll;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

#Artist{
color: #a5a5a5;
position: fixed;
top: 40px;
left: -500px;
animation-name: artist;
animation-duration: 30s;
z-index: -1;
width: 200px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: scroll;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: Check out the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: By auto scroll do you mean you want a user to open the popup and the text would automatically start to scroll, without the user doing anything?